# jQuery ui dialog box appears off view port

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, scroll

I am using jQuery ui [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), when the page height is longer that view port height, vertical scroll bar will appear, then, when user scroll the page, the dialog will get off view port area ..

Is there an option to make the dialog always within the viewport area no matter the scroll offset is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position:fixed; Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: shall I apply it at the .dialog?

Comment: According to the link you provided, You can apply it to "ui-dialog" class.